# Circular reference in declarations: Type Error: Object #<Object> has no method 'call'

Tags: node.js, typescript, commonjs

The 3 simple classes are set in three separate Typescript (1.0.1) files transpiled as CommonJS modules

`SubA` and `SubB` both inherit from `Klass`. 
`Klass` also imports `SubB`.

In `node`, running

```
var SubA = require('./SubA');
var sa = new SubA('blah');
sa.toSubB();
```

fails on the `super()` call in the `SubB` constructor with `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'call'`)

(edit: replacing SubA with SubB in the js code above, will not fail)

Do you see a way around this or there is just no possibility for `Klass` to import `SubB`?

Klass.ts

```
import SubB = require('./SubB')

class Klass {

    private name: string

    setName(name: string) {
        this.name = name
    }

    getName(): string {
        return this.name
    }

    createSubB(): SubB {
        return new SubB(name)
    }
}

export = Klass
```

SubA.ts

```
import Klass = require('./Klass')
import SubB = require('./SubB')

class SubA extends Klass {

    constructor(name:string) {

        super()
        this.setName(name)
    }

    toSubB(): SubB {
        return new SubB(this.getName())
    }
}

export = SubA
```

SubB.ts

```
import Klass = require('./Klass')
import SubA = require('./SubA')

class SubB extends Klass {

    constructor(name:string) {

        super()
        this.setName(name)
    }

    toSubA(): SubA {
        return new SubA(this.getName())
    }
}

export = SubB
```

`tsc` command line options: `--module commonjs  -target ES5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the order of `import` statements in `SubA`and `SubB`  fixed it